# How To Prevent AspNetUsers Table SQL Injection Attack?

Tags: model-view-controller, sql-injection, identity

We have a live ASP.NET MVC 5 website that uses ASP.NET Identity.  It appears to be the victim of an SQL injection attack on the aspnetusers table.  Both the PasswordHash and the SecurityStamp column values have HTML appended to them - in the form of links to drug sites within hidden div tags (display: none).

This then prevents any users from logging in to our website.

The only other thing to note is that we allow Facebook users to be authenticated using their Facebook account.

I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC and Identity and haven't really modified any of the authorisation code provided in my project.  Is there anything I can modify to prevent future attacks?

Comment: First step: Find any place you're accessing your database and use parametrized queries.

Comment: Firstly, what makes you think it's a SQL Injection attack? Secondly, use parameterised queries, or an ORM such as Entity Framework, that will get rid of most of your injection points.

Comment: I perhaps wrongfully presumed that an SQL injection attack resulted in content being inserted/appended to database records.  Also, we are using the Entity Framework to work with the Identity tables.

Comment: It's almost certainly not SQL Injection if you are using EF to talk to your Identity tables.

Comment: Thanks DavidG.  Do you have any ideas on where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

Found a vulnerability in another website using the same connection string.  Parameterised queries was the solution.